# Automate Git Parameter on Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

I'm currently working on a CI project where jenkins builds packages from changes made to a git repo, and I've run into a bit of a problem while using git parameters.

The name of the package is changed based on the number of the release, and so therefore I currently get a list of the current version numbers associated with the repo the application is built on top of through the git parameter plug in.

This part works fine. However, a user has to go into the jenkins app and pick the correct version number as a build parameter from the drop down menu before deploying the project. I want this part to be fully automated so that the jenkins script knows to pick the highest version number each time. This takes away the need for a user to go in and pick the correct number from the drop down menu each time they want to create a new package.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I currently get a list of the current version numbers […] through the git parameter plug in

From this, I will assume you mean that you're using Git tag or branch names (e.g. v1.0, v1.1, v2.0) to identify releases.

---

When you manually trigger a build of a job that uses the Git Parameter plugin, it fetches the list of tags (or branches etc.), and displays them in the web UI for you to choose from before the build actually starts, and then you have to scroll through and click the latest tag name.

When a build is triggered automatically (by a timer, another build, a commit hook etc.) then the build will just use the "Default Value" that you configured on the parameter. Which is no use.

I guess these are the two problems you might have been experiencing.

However, despite what some of the documentation/inline help seems to suggest, setting a default value is **not** mandatory.

By *not* setting a default value, combined with the "smart descending" sort order, you should be able to achieve the desired result. For example:

```groovy
pipeline {
  agent any
  triggers {
    // Trigger a build automatically every minute,
    // to demonstrate that automated builds will
    // correctly pick up the latest Git tag name
    cron('* * * * *')
  }
  parameters {
    // Sort the Git repo's tags in descending order of version, so
    // the newest one will appear at the top of the parameter list
    gitParameter name: 'MY_LATEST_TAG',
                 type: 'PT_TAG',
                 sortMode: 'DESCENDING_SMART'
  }
  stages {
    stage('blahem') {
      steps {
        // Clone the repo, at the tag specified by the parameter
        checkout([
          $class: 'GitSCM',
          userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-parameter-plugin']],
          branches: [[name: "refs/tags/${params.MY_LATEST_TAG}"]]
        ])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>(Note: if you're using a Pipeline (as opposed to a Freestyle job), you should first build the Pipeline once with a valid value as the branch name (e.g. `master` rather than `refs/tags/${params.MY_LATEST_TAG}`), to allow the SCM config to be picked up properly)</sup>

If you trigger a build of this Pipeline from the web UI, you'll see that the tags are correctly ordered in descending order of version:

```
git-parameter-0.9.11
git-parameter-0.9.10
git-parameter-0.9.9
git-parameter-0.9.8
…
```

However, if the default or non-smart sort order was used, the values would be compared as strings and so you'd end up with something like this (i.e. lexicographically correct, but semantically no good):

```
git-parameter-0.9.2
git-parameter-0.9.11
git-parameter-0.9.10
git-parameter-0.9.1
git-parameter-0.9.0
…
```

By **not** specifying a default value, when a build of this Pipeline is triggered automatically, the list of tags will be fetched at runtime and the item at the top of the (correctly sorted) list will be used as the parameter value.